# Wordpress : Fetch Comments for a specific Post ID in DESC order by Comment Date

Tags: wordpress, plugins, comments

I am trying to fetch Comments in a WP PLUGIN for a certain POST ID, order by Comment Date in DESCENDING Order that way LATEST Comments are displayed at the TOP. However, the following query does NOT work :

```
 $comments = get_comments(array('post_id' => $post->ID, 'status' => 'approve', 'orderby'=> 'comment_date','order' => 'DESC','parent' => '0'));
```

Can you tell me the exact query for the same ?

Any help would be great help. Thanks !

Comment: "Does not work" how?  Are you getting any results?  Results for the wrong post (or multiple posts)?  Results for the right post in the wrong order?  If it's in a function, have you added `global $post;`  somewhere before your call?

Comment: I think you can leave orderby and order because default values are comment_date_gmt and DESC (same as what you're trying to accomplish). See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments